# Change index variable within ruby loop

Tags: ruby, iteration

I realize this may be against ruby principle and may seem a bit silly, but I am curious to whether it possible to modify the index variable during iteration of a loop in ruby.

This practice is possible in Java/C with the for loop in this contrived example:

```
for (int k = 0; k < 10; k++)
{
   if (k == 5)
      k = 8;
}
```

As well, I am aware that it is possible to access an index variable with Enumerable#each_with_index, but I am interested with the ability to alter the variable in this instance rather than access it.

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: As fotanus said -- it is possible to mimic this code in ruby, but I can't imagine any real problem that would be solved this way.

Answer (score 5):

actually the for semantic is the following:

```
for(executed_once_before_all; test; execute_every_loop) { /* code */ }
```

and so, in ruby:

```
executed_once_before_all
while test do
  execute_every_loop
  # code
end
```

so your exemple is like this:

```
k = 0
while k < 10 do
  k = 8 if (k == 5)
  k += 1
end
```

Comment: Isn't that last `while` incorrect? `k` should be increased at the end of the loop, if not you won't use k with value 0 and at the end you'll have k == 10 when that value should not be considered.

Comment: yeah you are right, in the first for interation the last clause is not executed

Answer (score 0):

Changing `for` loop counter in Ruby does not change the number of iterations.

You can change the counter variable, but that will affect the current iteration only:

```
> for k in 0...10
>   k = 8 if k == 5
>   puts k
> end
0
1
2
3
4
8  # Note this!
6
7
8
9
```

The best way to achieve the desired behaviour is to use `while` loop as @fotanus suggested.

Of course, you can do that with `for` loop using `next` statements, but that's much more ugly:

```
for k in 0...10
  next if k > 5 && k <= 8
  ... do stuff ...
  next if k == 5
  ... do stuff ...
end
```

Answer (score -2):

You could do that, but Ruby programmers generally don't use the for loop (although it's available). You could also do something like this:

```
[0,1,2,3,4,5,8,9,10].each do |index|
  # your code here
end
```